# In app purchase of 'packs' with large amounts of data. Optimizing the user experience

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, large-files, updates

I'm developing an app with the option of in-app purchasing of audio packs, probably around 30 MB per pack, around 500 files. I want to start with say 10 packs available, and add new packs over time, maybe 4-5 per month. A given user is expected to have no more than 10 packs in use at any time. Here are a few considerations I would greatly appreciate advice / suggestions on:

1. Can I set the app up so that it downloads the audio files for a
   pack only once the pack has been purchased? Or do they need to be included in the main bundle, with an 'unlock' feature being the way to get access to them?
2. Can I give the user the option of deleting the audio files contained in a pack which has been 'finished', of course with the option of re-downloading it later - it has been paid for, after all.
3. Can I set up the app, so that the list of packs available is updated without having to re-submit through the app store every time?
4. If I need to replace a single file in one of the packs - how do I push this update out to the end user who has already installed the pack?
5. If I go with the option of including all the words in the main bundle - and I want to add more packs later, can the iPhone retain the original content so users with the original version only need to download the new content?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You can set it up so that content is downloadable from your own servers.
2. Yes, but you will have to keep track of which users have downloaded what. I believe there are API's the can assist you with this, such as `MKStoreKit` which you can find on git.
3. If the content is on your own servers, then you can just update that without having to resubmit the app. But you will have set this up intelligently so you can dynamically update the UI of the app based on info pinged from your server.
4. Not sure, but there probably is a way.
5. Not sure, but that does not seem like a logical approach, especially since you will be storing data on your own servers.

`iOS5 Programming Pushing The Limits` by `Napier` and `Kumar` provide a pretty good high level explanation on how this all works. You probably do need to do a bit of reading on it.

I hope this gets you on your way.

Comment: Hi Eric, thankyou very much for your reply. I was kind of hoping to be able to do this without using my own servers - ie through the apple store, but maybe this is not the way to go, especially given your answer to Q3, ie new in-app purchases would need a re-submission if the entire app for them to show up. Hmm, time to get my head down.

Comment: Done. I have since seen that with iOS 6, content linked to in-app purchasing will be available through the store. Not sure if I can wait that long, though, I'll be cutting off a lot of users if I implement iOS6 compatible only devices at this point.